# Help with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Should request: *site.ru/index.php?go=23&page=bla*
alter the form: *bla.site.ru/index.php?go=23*

That is, the user types in browser *bla.site.ru/index.php?go=23* and all information is passed to scripts that request *site.ru/index.php?go=23&page=bla*

It is prohibited to use redirect

Comment: This is a server-admin related question - it should be on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI}?page=%1 [L,QSA]
```